# Jump starting a User Form

Tags: excel, vba

Excel allows me to use an auto-created user form. This form is fairly close to what I want, but it needs tweaking.

Question: Is there a way to save the auto-generated form in such a way that I can then edit it?

I realize that I can create the form from within my VBA code with an application method, but it doesn't format all the fields properly, and I would like to add buttons to get the user to additional forms.

Comment: VBA is infinitely more capable of configuration of forms and actions.

Comment: If you save the workbook the form you created will be saved with it and can then be edited. However, you might also add more controls and/or modify the properties of the controls you already created.